# Linear model assumptions: what is $I$?

Tags: regression, linear-model, normality-assumption, assumptions, notation

For linear model I have some assumptions for errors, for example
errors are normally distributed
$\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2I)$.
What does $I$ show in here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the identity matrix, square and with all $0$s except for $1$s on the diagonal, so $\sigma^2I$ means equal variances $\sigma^2$ and no correlations.